# How to choose a regex pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, substring

I'm studying Python 3 but I'm struggling to get regex with the re module.

Here's my problem: I have the string

`phrase = "s000000000 s1133122 s21 s3 s4 s5212638476234857634 s6 s7 s8 s9000"`

and, using the function

`re.findall(pattern, phrase)`

I'd like to extract:

1. s0-s9 strings without the additional characters;
2. s0-s3 strings without the additional characters;
3. s0-s3 strings with the additional characters;
4. s4-s9 strings with the additional characters.

I managed to accomplish the first three tasks by using these following patterns:

1. `pattern = "s[0-9]"`
2. `pattern = "s[0-3]"`
3. `pattern = "s[0-3]+"`

For the last task, though, I tried to replicate what I did in the third one and used

`pattern = "s[4-9]+"`

but, instead of getting as result

`["s4", "s5212638476234857634", "s6", "s7", "s8", "s9000"]`

I get

`["s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8", "s9"]`

Why is that? What am I missing? The instructions on the book I'm studying from states that the plus sign means "one or more characters", and the s[0-3]+ pattern in fact works, but I cannot make it work for this specific problem.

Comment: If you type `'s[4-9]+'` you match a string which starts with a `s` followed only by digits from 4 to 9. `"s5212638476234857634"` has numbers lower 4 and `"s9000"` does not match this rule, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```py
s[4-9]\d*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3mRJ0H/1). *Note*: you might want to start matching from a word boundary if `s` should not be preceded with any word chars, `\bs[4-9]\d*`. In Python, it would look like `r'\bs[4-9]\d*'`.

*Details*:

- `s` - an `s` char
- `[4-9]` - a digit from `4` to `9`
- `\d*` - zero or more digits.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3CT61b):

```py
import re
rx = r"s[4-9]\d*"
text = "s000000000 s1133122 s21 s3 s4 s5212638476234857634 s6 s7 s8 s9000"
print( re.findall(rx, text) )
# => ['s4', 's5212638476234857634', 's6', 's7', 's8', 's9000']
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a great feature, my book doesn't mention the /d. The thing is: why s[0-3]+ works and s[4-9]+ doesn't? I cannot get it

Comment: @jnsen76 `[0-3]+` matches one or more `0`, `1`, `2` or `3` chars, it does not match `4`, `5`, etc.

Comment: Ok nevermind, I played with the editor and I got why it doesn't work with [3-9]+. Thank you. The regex tester is a great thing BTW, thank you for introducing it to me